# App apk updated but screenshot and description don't

Tags: android, google-play

I've updated an app on play store 6 days ago. I've replaced older screenshots and description with new one. The apk is updated but I'm not able to see latest screenshot and description. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I had pressed the Submit Update button. :) Actually I'm able to see the updated screenshot on my device. But not on desktop browser and some other mobiles.

Comment: Actually I had updated it thrice since i'd updated my app as it was not reflecting. The app version was 1.1 I changed it to 1.2 then updated the description and screens. But still its showing the older screens. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.startv.gumrah&hl=en. Please refer the link.

Comment: But it has already been 6 days. Can you please tell me what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, Can anybody help me with this...I'm not able to figure out the problem. Thank you.